# Cumulative angles

Tags: geometry

Say I draw a straight line up a piece of paper perpendicular to the bottom of the page a certain distance and then veer off at a certain angle and continue with another straight line and continue to do this a few times with random angles and random lengths of straight line. My question is is there a way I can ascertain the cumulative “height” of line from the starting point without having to break it down into multiple triangles and using sines and cosines?

Comment: How else do you propose to find the vertical projection without using the given angles? Seems like the most straightforward approach to me.

Comment: It is the most straightforward approach but with lots of lines and angles it can take a very long time to do. Is there a way to sum up the angles whether they move in a clockwise direction or counter clockwise and sum up the lengths and arrive at the answer? I guess what I am asking is what would be the most efficient method of determining the end height?

Answer (score 0):

Kind of--you may represent each line segment as a vector with horizontal and vertical ($x$ and $y$) components. Take the sum of the $y$ components to find the total height.

Depending on what tools you have, you could either do this with inverse trig functions or with a straight edge and ruler.

Comment: Thank you Lanier. I was wondering about the use of vectors. I think my question could be analogous to a ship leaving port and sailing in different directions over the course of its journey.

Comment: That's right--it's basically a bearings problem

Answer (score 0):

The y components of the different vectors is basically equivalent to the sines when each vector is broken down into the hypotenuse of a different right triangle, so either approach works.